# What has changed in Terminal.app in OS X 10.8?

Tags: terminal, macos

Just upgraded OS X to Mountain Lion and noticed that Terminal.app version has changed from 2.2.3 to 2.3. Unfortunately, can`t find any information about what has changed. Do you know if there is any place that provides very detailed changelog regarding OS and Apps?

Answer (score 1):

The new feature is that it works with mountain lion. Apple updates to a new minor release version number of terminal with every new edition of osx

Answer (score 0):

Probably very little. Certainly does not look like much has…

On the second thought: did previous version allow to "Open man Page" for selected word when you double-tap? [Checked, it did, this was added in Lion]